# child_process stdout complete event

Tags: node.js

I am using below code to transcode a video

```
var input_file = fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path);
var output_file = fs.createWriteStream(filePathh);

var args = ['-i', 'pipe:0', '-f', 'mp4', '-strict', 'experimental', '-movflags', 'frag_keyframe', 'pipe:1'];
var trans_proc = child.spawn('avconv', args, null);

input_file.pipe(trans_proc.stdin);
trans_proc.stdout.pipe(output_file);

trans_proc.stderr.on('end', function (data) {
    // console.log(data.toString());

    var fileid = new ObjectID();

    var gridStoreWrite = new GridStore(db, fileid, req.files.file.name, "w", {});

    gridStoreWrite.writeFile(filePathh, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            //console.log("Write Error");
            //fileId_ = null;
            res.send(err);
            // cb(null, true);
        } else {
            //console.dir(result);
            // fileId_ = fileid;
            console.log(fileid);
            res.send(fileid);
            // cb(null, true);
        }
    });
});
```

But this is writing file to GridFS multiple times. How can I fix that to write to GridFS when conversion is complete.

Comment: If you're listening for 'end' then it should not fire more than once. However it looks like you were previously listening for 'data', which **could** occur more than once.

Comment: @mscdex How can I fix that

Comment: You should be listening to `trans_proc.on('end')` and not the `end` event of the stderr stream.  To have access to `stdout` and `stderr` you'll have to capture the data on those events.  Alternately, you could use `.execFile` to just get the complete output at the end of the process run.